# How do I pass a @State binding to the Content closure of a custom container?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-state

I'm starting to play with custom containers and I'm stuck trying to send the @State var across. Sample code:

```
struct ZoomCardView<Content: View>: View {
    let contentDefault: ((Binding<Bool>)) -> Content
    let contentZoomed: (Binding<Bool>) -> Content
    
    init(@ViewBuilder defaultContent: @escaping (Binding<Bool>) -> Content, @ViewBuilder zoomed: @escaping (Binding<Bool>) -> Content) {
        self.contentDefault = defaultContent
        self.contentZoomed = zoomed
    }
    
    @State private var isShowing: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            if isShowing {
                self.contentZoomed($isShowing)
                    .transition(.scale(scale: 0, anchor: .center))
            } else {
                self.contentDefault($isShowing)
                    .transition(.scale(scale: 0, anchor: .center))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is that the callsite would render the content and provide the mechanism to toggle the `isShowing` var. The rationale is to allow the callsite to decide which gesture or UI element controls the toggle:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZoomCardView { isShowing in
            Button(action: {
                isShowing.toggle()  <---- *** Error (see below)
            }, label: {
                Text("Open")
            })
        } zoomed: { isShowing in
            Button(action: {
                isShowing.toggle()  <---- *** Error (see below)
            }, label: {
                Text("Zoomed")
            })
        }
        .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
        .cornerRadius(15)
        .shadow(radius: 5)
    }
}
```

The issue: I get a `Cannot call value of non-function type 'Binding<() -> ()>` in the two `isShowing.toggle()` lines above. I'm not sure why. Any ideas?

Comment: `isShowing` is a `Binding<Bool>` - it doesn't have `.toggle()` like `Bool` does. You can, instead, do `isShowing.wrappedValue = !isShowing.wrappedValue`, or write a an extension on `Binding where Value == Bool` to do that

Comment: Totally makes sense, @NewDev. Thanks a lot.